# Explain what this fail() method does in this junit test

Tags: java, junit, try-catch

I am having a bit of trouble understanding with the fail() method for JUnit tests does in practice. I looked around online and saw from the junit website that fail(java.lang.String message) "Fails a test with the given message." In the JUnit test I'm looking at, this is the following code:

```
@Test (expected = RuntimeException.class)
    public void testBadCombine(){
      AvocadoPortion ap1 = new AvocadoPortion(amount1);
      AvocadoPortion ap2 = new AvocadoPortion(amount2);
      IngredientPortion ap3 = ap1.combine(ap2);
      CrabPortion cp1= new CrabPortion(2);

      ap1.combine(cp1);
      fail("Expected RuntimeException to be thrown");
}
```

Can someone please explain what the (expected = RuntimeException.class) does?

And if a RuntimeException IS thrown, does the fail("Expected RuntimeException to be thrown"); line not get executed, making the JUnit test succeed?

Why is the ap.1combine(cp1); line not under a try and catch block? (When do you need to use a try and catch block?)

As you can see I'm pretty confused and could use some clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone please explain what the (expected = RuntimeException.class) does?

It requires the test to throw a `RuntimeException` in order to pass.

> And if a RuntimeException IS thrown, does the fail("Expected RuntimeException to be thrown"); line not get executed, making the JUnit test succeed?

Exactly. This is technically redundant because of the `expected` element above. The only difference is that *any* `Throwable` would pass this check, but not the previous one.

> Why is the ap.1combine(cp1); line not under a try and catch block? (When do you need to use a try and catch block?)

Try/catch is normally used for gracefully handling an exceptional situation. In other words, if an issue comes up, we want to solve it or work around it and then proceed normally. Here, we take the opposite approach and propagate the exception instead of handling it, so JUnit can know the exception was thrown.

Answer (score 3):

The reasonable options to make that testing code more clear:

A) just use `expected`

```
@Test (expected = RuntimeException.class)
public void testBadCombine(){
  AvocadoPortion ap1 = new AvocadoPortion(amount1);
  AvocadoPortion ap2 = new AvocadoPortion(amount2);
  IngredientPortion ap3 = ap1.combine(ap2);
  CrabPortion cp1= new CrabPortion(2);
  ap1.combine(cp1);
```

}

B) If required, do some specific testing on your exception ...

```
@Test
public void testBadCombine(){
  AvocadoPortion ap1 = new AvocadoPortion(amount1);
  AvocadoPortion ap2 = new AvocadoPortion(amount2);
  IngredientPortion ap3 = ap1.combine(ap2);
  CrabPortion cp1= new CrabPortion(2);
  try {
    ap1.combine(cp1);
    fail("should have thrown");
  } catch (TheExactExceptionYouExpect e) {
    assertThat(e.getSomeProperty(), is(whatever));
  }
}
```

You would prefer option "A)" - you only turn to "B") when in fact you want to assert certain properties of that exception thrown by the code under test.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, it is redundant to have both the `expected` and the `fail()`. One of them would be enough and hence appropriate.

For most exception types, you are also correct that if you want to use `fail()` rather than `expected`, you would use a `try`-`catch` statement with `fail()` in the end of the `try` part. In this respect, `RuntimeException` is special since it is the parent exception of all *unchecked*  exceptions. Since no statement in the method can throw any *checked* exceptions, we know that either an unchecked exception is thrown, that is, a `RuntimeException`, or the method will reach the call to `fail()`. One or the other, not both.